# How to use a method in a model class that is defined in a helper module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am just trying to access the simple_format helper

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SimpleHelper

 def body_symbols_output_html
    arc_simple_format(body_symbols_output)
  end
```

and in lib/simple_helper.rb

```
module SimpleHelper
  def arc_simple_format txt
    simple_format txt
  end
end
```

and get

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `simple_format' for #<Note:0x007f7fbb913088>):
  lib/simple_helper.rb:4:in `arc_simple_format'
```

How would I access simple_format? I know accessing view level helpers is a bad idea but this is just feeding an API.

Comment: `simple_format` method is missing in SimpleHelper. Where did you define it?

Comment: its an action_view helper http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html

Comment: You need to include it then in SimpleHelper.

Answer (score 6):

You should simply include the proper module:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
```

what I'd suggest though is to avoid to spoil your class with all those methods, so you could create a Helper class in your class:

```
class Note
  delegate :simple_format, to: :helper

  def helper
    Helper.instance
  end

  private

  class Helper
    include Singleton
    include ::ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  end
end
```